# Is V8 snapshot enabled in official Node.js binary?

Tags: node.js, v8

From [configure 1](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/configure#L811) and [configure 2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/configure#L957) , it looks like V8 snapshot configuration is enabled by default. [CI build log](https://ci.nodejs.org/job/node-compile-windows/9085/label=win-vs2015/consoleText) also shows that `v8_use_snapshot` is set to true.

However, why I don't see `native_blob.bin` and `snapshot_blob.bin` in official distribution? Chrome and Electron have these binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js embeds the contents of those `*_blob.bin` files directly into the binary. This is configured [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/common.gypi#L32) (the comment there sounds like a misunderstanding of what the flag does, so I'm not sure whether this is intentional, but either way it probably doesn't hurt).

Comment: Ah, I see #define V8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA and V8_USE_SNAPSHOT are two separate things. Thanks!